# PostgreSql ошибка ключа

Tags: sql, postgresql

добавил новые столбцы, хочу внести новые данные ключем ID

```
 INSERT INTO users
    (id, address, job)
    VALUES
    (2, 'Astana', 'ingener'),
    (3, 'Almaty', 'ingener'),
    (4, 'Karagandy', 'ingener');
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id         integer PRIMARY KEY,
    name       varchar(30),
    age         integer,
    address    varchar(30),
    job        varchar(30),
    bornyear     varchar(30),

);
```

выводит следующую ошибку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Операция insert добавляет новые записи (строки). А для изменения значения столбцов в существующий записях надо использовать update

Comment: `Nur-Sultan` же.

Comment: А где структура таблицы-то? или нам предлагается её придумать?

Answer (score 2):

добавить в

```
INSERT ... ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE SET address=excluded.address, job=excluded.job, bornyear=excluded.bornyear
```

Answer (score 0):

Подробно об инструкции `UPDATE` в PostgreSQL: [тут](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-update.html).

Запрос на обновление:

```
UPDATE Users SET address = 'Astana', job = 'ingener' WHERE id = 2;
```

Два других по аналогии.

**Об ошибке:**
Ваша таблица уже содержит значения первичного ключа равные 2,3,4. Для изменентя данных воспользуйтесь инструкцией `UPDATE`.